# Filling up placeholders in string

Tags: python, mysql, string

I have in mind a dynamic way of creating MySQL statement which has to be filled up with values passed from an outside function.

```
def check_id(table_name=None, *args):
""""""
  args = args[0]
  # print args, type(args), len(args)
  vals = [ tuple(elem.values()) for elem in args ]

  if isinstance(args, list):
    columns = []
    for idx, key in enumerate(args[0].keys()):
      if idx == len(args[0].keys()):
        columns.append((key, "= '%s'"))
      columns.append((key, "= '%s', AND"))

    columns = ' '.join("`%s` %s" % x for x in columns)
   else:
     print "NOT A LIST"
  sql = """SELECT id FROM %(table_name)s
         WHERE %(columns)s;""" % {'table_name':table_name, 'columns':vals}
  print sql
```

columns would be created as follow:

```
`size` = '%s', AND `resource_group_id` = '%s', AND `description` = '%s', AND `name` = '%s', AND `created` = '%s', AND `url` = '%s', AND `format` = '%s', AND `res_geo_0` = '%s', AND `tracking_summary_total` = '%s', AND `revision_timestamp` = '%s', AND `res_geo_1` = '%s', AND `state` = '%s', AND `last_modified` = '%s', AND `webstore_last_updated` = '%s', AND `url_type` = '%s', AND `position` = '%s', AND `revision_id` = '%s', AND `webstore_url` = '%s', AND `resource_type` = '%s', AND `tracking_summary_recent` = '%s', AND
```

How would I fill up the the placeholders '%s' with values from vals. Any idea? Are those even treated as placeholder with python? or Is this a wrong approach?

Comment: It's not very clear to me what you're trying to do. "%s %s" %(a, b) would substitute the string representation of a and b into the string

Comment: [Format string syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax)